# Shadow Padding bug for enlarged Floating Action Button for Xamarin.Android with AndroidSDK API 19 and less

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

For my project, I need a bigger Floating Action Button (FAB) (I know it goes against principles of Google Material Design, but can't do much about that). I know that FAB has default and mini sizes to them, but I need bigger. To get bigger size, I made custom button class that inherits FAB class:

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Java.Lang;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;

public class BiggerFloatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton
{
    [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", "")]
    public BiggerFloatingActionButton(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V", "")]
    public BiggerFloatingActionButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) { }
    [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V", "")]
    public BiggerFloatingActionButton(Context attrscontext, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(attrscontext, attrs, defStyleAttr) { }
    protected BiggerFloatingActionButton(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = this.MeasuredWidth;
        int height = this.MeasuredHeight;

        this.SetMeasuredDimension((int)(width * 1.75f), (int)(height * 1.75f));
        //base.OnMeasure(width, height);
    }
}
```

In result, it works, but there are shadow padding problems on Android API 19 and probably lower:
[image]

While on Android API 20 it looks alright:"
[image]

Does anyone know the clue why the former effect happens?

Usage of my custom FAB is as follows:

```
var buttons = new List<BiggerFloatingActionButton>();
foreach (var item in categories)
{
    var button = new BiggerFloatingActionButton(this);
    var iconIdentifier = this.Resources.GetIdentifier(item.Icon, "drawable", this.ApplicationContext.PackageName);
    var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, iconIdentifier);
    button.SetImageDrawable(drawable);
    buttons.Add(button);
}

var layout = this.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linear_main);
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
    layout.AddView(button);
}
```

For reference, I use the newest Xamarin for Visual Studio version (4.2.0.695) and newest Xamarin.Android (7.0.12).
Thank you!

Edit:
Here is MVCE - https://ufile.io/b691.

Comment: Can you upload a MVCE(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this issue in a project? You can add a link to a hosting provider in your post.

Comment: @JonDouglas Adeed MVCE to the question. Also you can download it here: https://ufile.io/b691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that `SetMeasuredDimension()` adds shadow padding on KitKat and below: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#200

You can see the following comment:

> ```
>    /**
>      * Pre-Lollipop we use padding so that the shadow has enough space to be drawn. This method
>      * offsets our layout position so that we're positioned correctly if we're on one of
>      * our parent's edges.
>      */
> ```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#729

Thus this can easily be fixed by removing any elevation which will remove the shadow via the `CompatElevation` property:

`this.CompatElevation = 0f;`

Now your large FAB should look great on < API 19!

Comment: Thank you, that works, but there is additional problem with the Floating Action Buttons when their size is enlarged - they no longer are symmetrical circles but ellipse with width no equal to height. And setting width equal to height via SetMeasuredDimension does not help. Any ideas why it is? This problem is can be replicated in the same project and can be seen in the screenshot I provided too (if you look closer it's height is higher than it's width).

Comment: Open up a new question. The original question should be considered solved.

Comment: Well, the original question is why the enlarged Floating Action Buttons look weird. Part of it is due to shadow glitch which you thankfully helped me to resolve, but part is due to to circle not being the correct size. I fear if I make another question like this, it will be considered a duplicate.

Comment: These are very specific questions that should have self-contained questions for each of them. Solving all of them in one question is very broad. For example you can edit this original question to say `Why do shadow paddings appear under my custom FAB in KitKat`. Then you can make a new question regarding the elongation of the shape's width vs. height. Sadly you only ask `Does anyone know the clue why the former effect happens?`. This is very broad and the elongation isn't that noticeable unless you specifically mention it in your question. Where-as the shadow padding is very noticeable.

Comment: To answer the following question without much digging, the APIs as shown in the source show exactly what's going on: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java In short, the APIs differ for compatibility Pre-Lollipop and thus you would need to override something to get the desired effect on < API 19 items.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will open new question about the other side effect. It most likely is caused by some inner workings of ImageButton implementation in Android. Need to dig deeper.